# Should shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange work in the same way as invalidateLayout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

One can call [`invalidateLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/invalidateLayout) directly on an `UICollectionView` or one could implement [`shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:) and return `YES`.

Now I observed that in my implementation both work different. `invalidateLayout` works in my case as expected, but `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` behaves differently so that the layout looks destroyed. In detail, on orientation change the width of the cells is not updated and so the `minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing` is different and this is not working for my layout. Especially, the number of items in a row is wrong, because of the not updated width.

If I look into the documentation [`invalidateLayoutWithContext:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/invalidateLayoutWithContext:) is called when `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` returns `YES`. But how does this method works differently then directly calling `invalidateLayout`?

Comment: Have you tested if `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange=true` changes any behaviour?